# Nodejs. Unhandled Promise Rejection

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to test some functionality. Inside the routes.js file, i placed this code:

```
async function getPic(arg) {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch(/*{headless: false}*/);
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto(arg);
    await page.setViewport({width: 1000, height: 500})
    await page.screenshot({path: 'pic.png'});

    await broswer.close();
}
```

I read about async/await (it is the first time i use it). Though i get an error message and the code does not work:

```
(node:5896) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Navigation Timeout Exceeded
: 30000ms exceeded
    at Promise.then (C:\...\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\NavigatorWatcher.js:73:21
)
    at <anonymous>
(node:5896) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This
error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch
block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection
 id: 1)
(node:5896) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are depre
cated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the
 Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Unfortunately i do not know what this means. I found out a similar question on stackoverflow here:
[NodeJS Unhandled Promise Rejection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46838859/nodejs-unhandled-promise-rejection)

But unfortunately does not make things clear for me on how to solve this error.

When i tested this snippet of code in a standalone node environment - meaning just this code without anything else, as i do in my project, then somehow it works.

When i place this function inside my routes.js file, and then invoke the function when a post event happens then i get the error.

Here is the code that invokes this function:

```
app.post('/sc', function(req, res){
        var url = req.body.convo
        console.log(url)

        getPic(url);
    })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use await before call async function and wrapp await call into try catch construction.

```
app.post('/sc', async (req, res) => {
    const url = req.body.convo
    try {
      var picture = await getPic(url);
      //some logic or render response
    } catch (error){
       //here you should handle error
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to `await getPic(url);`.

Also you have browser misspelled in `await broswer.close();`